# Metrics for programmer self evaluation

Tags: metrics

I'm programming from home and I want to know whether I'm more or less productive programming at 10 AM than I am when I'm programming at 8PM.

What metrics should I use to determine an answer to the question?

Comment: 1/time spent on internet

Comment: Too subjective.  What do you think "productive" means in terms of your programming?

Comment: @Dan: That's begging the question.

Comment: @Christian: I could think of a dozen meaningful things that you *could* measure a programmer on.  I could equally come up with a dozen reasons why any of those things are completely irrelevant or inconsistent in terms of productivity.  I think this is too subjective a question to be answered.

Comment: @Dan, no metric is perfect and each has it's advantages and disadvantages. That however doesn't mean that I shouldn't make evidence-based decision about whether to work in the morning or at night.

Comment: @Christian: I don't think you can make a meaningful evidence-based decision on something that's this subjective.  You might as well base your decision (as ILMV suggested) on the amount of coffee you consume; it's as strong an indication as anything else you'll measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the debate in the question's comments, a bunch of arbitrary productivity-ish metrics you could measure...

- lines of code written
- user stories/tasks completed
- bugs fixed
- tests written
- tests passing first time
- bugs found
- code churn vs new code (i.e. "right first time" vs "rewritten repeatedly")
- %age of time in IDE vs debugging
- %age of time in IDE vs non-work applications
- code quality (using another similarly arbitrary measure like FxCop compliance or cyclic complexity)
- code performance (against some arbitrary or customer-specified benchmark)

The best metrics tend to be combinations - say, "average of bugs found per line of code written" - rather than a single measure.  Still, these are all subjective and innacurate.

I'd suggest the best thing to do is decide what your *goal* is when you're programming.  Is it to produce high-quality code, or super-performant realtime code, or mission-critical-must-be-bug-free code, or do you just need to ship something that works in the shortest time?  Until you've defined "productive", it's hard to suggest what would be a meaningful measurement.

Comment: I guess "arbitrary" is the key word here, i would love to add "absurd" but managers won´t like it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is some established method for measuring productivity in programmers but assuming alertness and focus has a direct impact on productivity, I suppose you could set yourself some kind of mental arithmetic test with randomised questions and answers and take it at regular intervals.

It's a tricky one because you can't measure by lines, or problems solved (because they vary in scale and difficulty.) In fact, [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/HighNotes.html) suggests that when attempting to measure programmer productivity, there is almost no correllation between the time it takes to complete a task and the quality of the finished product.